How to make a non-backing property serializable in Kotlin
Given a data class like:
@Serializable
data class Person(
    val name: String,
    val birthDate: Long,
) {
    val age get() = /* calculate age */
}

How do I include age in serialization? I know that I can use Transient to exclude a property.
According to the Basic Serialization guide only backing fields are serializable in the example. But it does not mention how to make non-backing fields (properties) serializable. Is there any way to include age in serialization without a hugely overkill solution that requires writing a custom serializer?
An alternative would be to use a backing field and assign it on init {} or pass it on instantiation-site but this seems quite hacky to me.

How do you even expect this to work? Your requirement doesn't make sense. The serializer has no idea how age is calculated. What do you want it to return for an instance that has just been deserialized? Do you want the age property to be whatever it was when it was last serialized? Why? That would mean it's no longer a calculated property, and whatever definition the property has would have to be ignored. Consider, for example, val age get() = System.currentTimeMillis() - what should age return after it gets deserialized?

It's not supposed to be deserialized. This is a case where the data class is only used to serialize a JSON on server side. In the deserialization case, it could simply skip the property. I'm only talking about serialization, not deserialization. In your example, deserialization can simply be skipped. But for serialization every time it is serialized, the client would receive a JSON where age is different every time.

Am I right to assume that you want to use the serialization not as a way to store or transport the serialized data and then at some other point of time deserialize it again? Probably you just want to transfrom the object to a string that you can use somewhere else? In that case you would probably want age to be set to whatever the get function returns at the time of serialization and the whole deserialization problematic described by @k314159 won't apply. Is that correct? In that case a custom toString function would probably be best.

@Leviathan the serialization is used to create a JSON sent back to a client request via HTTP. The field can be different every time, that's okay since it's the result of a getter. I don't need deserialization in this case and even if I was to deserialize it, I would simply want it to skip the getters.

@Leviathan JSON is a requirement. toString is not suitable. I'm not going to write a custom parser or serializer just for this use case. I thought there could be an attribute like @Transient but for inclusion instead of exclusion.

I think we can close this question, it's obvious now that this use case is not supported, for good reasons, and there are ways around it, like assigning the values in init {} or assigning the value directly in class body or constructor as default (all of that requires deterministic calculation and read-only inputs). Alternatively you could use a writable backing field with getters and setters and change the dependent property from there.

I don't think there is some built-in way to do this.
One alternative to a custom serializer would be to use an additional data class that can be serialized as intended. Remove @Serializable from Person and create this new data class:
@Serializable
data class PersonSerializable(
    val name: String,
    val birthDate: Long,
    val age: Int,
)

You can then convert a Person to an instance that will be serializable as intended with this:
fun Person.serializable(): PersonSerializable = PersonSerializable(
    name = name,
    birthDate = birthDate,
    age = age,
)

Now you can use this to create a JSON string of a Person instance:
val json = Json.encodeToString(person.serializable())

There is still some overhead, but perhaps better yet than a custom serializer. It all depends on your actual use case.

Short answer: You can't with built-in Serialization methods.
Workaround without a custom serializer: Give it a backing field and hide the constructor
This is based on the assumption that age is calculated based on the birthDate. property.
You could do this:
@Serializable
data class Person private constructor(
    val name: String,
    val birthDate: Long,
    @SerialName("age")
    private var serialAge: Int,
) {
    constructor(name: String, birthDate: Long) : this(name, birthDate, calculateAge(birthDate))

    val age: Int
        get() {
            val newValue = calculateAge(birthDate)
            serialAge = newValue
            return newValue
        }

    companion object {
        fun calculateAge(birthDate: Long): Int {
            // Calculate
        }
    }
}


Thanks. That's one of my suggestions in the comments.
